# Reversing a merge commit on BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

So I've got a feature branch that I wanted to merge into my dev branch, but without thinking during my pull request I've synced the branches which has created a merge commit from dev->feature branch before I merged feature->dev. But dev has a lot of stuff I don't want in my feature branch and I need to revert the merge.
I've tried:

```
git checkout feature
git revert #mergecommit
```

but its giving me

```
error: commit #mergecommit is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed
```

I'm stuck at this point and really don't want to mess the branches up trying to revert this badly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+commit+is+a+merge+but+no+%22-m%22+option+was+given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `git reset HEAD~1 && git push -f` That should rewrite the history and "undo" the merge. Just make sure everyone who is working on it pulls the updated HEAD or it will cause problems.

Comment: Do I have to specify the commit using this method? Or will it just reset the last commit

Comment: HEAD~1 is one commit behind HEAD, HEAD~2 is two commits etc.

Comment: Pay attention: this is a dangerous technique. It works, however.